# PHP - Listar os arquivos em um diretório

Tags: php, html

Tenho mais de mil paginas em `html`, gostaria que meu `script` abaixo listar todos os arquivos em um diretório ao invés de serem carregados manualmente, hoje tenho que fazer **um** a **um**. Está inviável!

Por favor vejam o código abaixo:

```
<?php

    $url = "lugar-amaricano-fundo-transparente-yangz-cp0012447.html"; /* ******** OBSERVAÇÃO: TEM COMO O script listar os arquivos em um diretório, ao invés de serem carregados manualmente? ******* */
    $content  = trim(file_get_contents($url));

    /*
        Função generica pode ser usada para pegar qualquer dado
        Retorna variável entre os valosres $ini(inicio) e $end(fim)
        $con = retorno do conteudo referênte ao html ou url
        $ini = inicio
        $end = fim
    */
    function getValues($ini, $end, $con){
        $value = explode( $ini , $con);
        $val = explode($end , $value[1] );
        return $val[0];
    }

    /*
        Função que retorna ID da marca
        retorna ID da marca passado como parâmetro.
        $val = marca
    */
    function getId($val){
        $array = str_split($val);
        $length = count($array);
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            if($value == "_"){
                $ini = $key+4;
            }            
        }   

        return substr($val,$ini,3);
    }

    $titulo = getValues("<h1>", "</h1>", $content);
    $marca = getValues('<li>Marca: ', "</li>", $content);
    $modelo = getValues('<li id="modeloDoProduto">', "</li>", $content);
    $disponibilidade = getValues('<h4 class="stockProduto">', "</h4>", $content);
    $preco = getValues('<h2  id="precoDoProduto">', "</h2>", $content);
    $unidade = getValues('<p></p>', "</div>", $content);
    $id = getId($marca);

    echo 'Titulo: '.$titulo.'<br/>';
    echo 'Marca: '.$marca.'<br/>';
    echo $modelo.'<br/>';
    echo $disponibilidade.'<br/>';
    echo 'Preco: '.$preco.'<br/>';
    echo 'Unidade: '.$unidade.'<br/>';
    // echo 'id: '.$id.'<br/>'; /* ******** OBSERVAÇÃO: NÃO PRECISO DESTE ID ******* */

    /* ******** INÍCIO DA INCLUSÃO DE NOVOS PARAMENTROS ******* */
    $urldaimagem = getValues('<ul class="thumbnails">', "</ul>", $content);
    $explode = explode(' ', $urldaimagem);
    // o explode retorna uma matriz
    $urldaimagem = $explode[26];
    $urldaimagem2 = $urldaimagem;   
    $urldaimagem3 = str_replace('href="../image/cache/catalog/fornecedor1/', 'http://www.comprenet.com.br/image/cache/catalog/fornecedor1/', $urldaimagem2);
    $urldaimagem4 = str_replace('"', '', $urldaimagem3);

    $empresa = str_replace('href="../image/cache/catalog/fornecedor1/', '', $urldaimagem2);
    $empresa2 = str_replace('-500x500.jpg"', '', $empresa);

    echo 'URL da Imagem: '.$urldaimagem4.'<br/>';

    echo 'Codigo na empresa: '.$empresa2.'<br/>';
    echo 'URL do Produto: '.$url.'<br/>';

    $descricao = getValues('<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-description">', "</div>", $content);
    echo 'Descrição do Produto: '.$descricao.'<br/>';
    echo '******************************'.'<br/>';
    /* ******** FIM DA INCLUSÃO DE NOVOS PARAMENTROS ******* */

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o scandir: [documentação aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.scandir.php)

Segue um exemplo simples da documentação:

```
<?php
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);

print_r($files1);
print_r($files2);


/*
Saida:
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => foo.txt
    [4] => somedir
)
Array
(
    [0] => somedir
    [1] => foo.txt
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => ..
    [4] => .
)
*/
```

Não apliquei a solução ao seu código pela dificuldade de testar. Porem, o uso é simples e certamente você conseguira utilizar sem problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo para filtrar somente os arquivos com a extensão `.html`.
Irá retornar um array com o nome dos arquivos, onde `path` é o caminho da pasta onde estão seus arquivos.

Código:

```
<?php

$path = 'C:\\exemplo\\';

$files = str_replace($path, "", glob($path . "*.html"));

print_r($files);

?>
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
   [0] => teste.html
)
```