# Listar e Ler arquivo .txt em PHP e pegar valores específicos separados por pastas

Tags: php

Ola, Gostaria de uma GRANDE ajuda de vocês.. rsrs
o que preciso basicamente, é criar um sistema que me retorne o em `$variáveis` separadas, para printar depois, os valores do arquivo thema.txt
Como por exemplo o **WP**..

Em um arquivo .PHP, que estaria fora da pasta THEMAS, retornaria os temas separados pelas pastas, e suas informações no arquivo thema.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código atual que estou é esse:

```
<?php
    // atribuição a variável $dir
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator( './themes/' );

    // atribui o valor de $dir para $file em loop
    foreach($dir as $file ) {
        // verifica se o valor de $file é diferente de '.' ou '..'
        // e é um diretório (isDir)
        if (!$file->isDot() && $file->isDir()) { 
            // atribuição a variável $dname
            $dname = $file->getFilename();

            // imprime o nome do diretório
            echo $dname."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Mas ele apenas me retorna os nomes das pastas.
Preciso que me retorne as informações de dentro dos arquivos localizados nas pastas listadas.

Comment: Já tentou algo, poderia fornecer o código?

Comment: A pouco respondi uma pergunta com ideia parecida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177327/php-listar-os-arquivos-em-um-diret%c3%b3rio/177329#177329. Vê se essa solução te ajuda.